# Leitura de Arquivo txt incorreta

Tags: delphi

Bom estou lendo a seguinte informação de um txt

```
0016009993|GuilhermeLima|Azul|4|21|basico+completo|6
```

após ler estou separando os conteudos usando os delimitadores "|" para separar em memos, com o código abaixo.

```
  begin
    Linha.Delimiter:='|';
    Linha.DelimitedText:=Texto[i];
    cod:=Linha.Strings[0];
    nome:=Linha.Strings[1];
    cor:=Linha.Strings[2];
    codv := linha.strings[3];
    idadade:=Linha.Strings[4];
    tipo:=Linha.Strings[5];
    id:=Linha.Strings[6];
    try
      memo1.lines.add(cod);
      memo2.lines.add(nome);
      memo3.lines.add(cor);
      memo7.Lines.Add(codv);
      memo4.Lines.Add(idade);
      memo5.Lines.Add(tipo);
      memo6.Lines.Add(id);
    except
      ShowMessage('Erro!!! A base de dados não está no padrão correto!');
```

Até ai tudo bem, porem se no txt estiver dessa maneira

```
0016009993|Guilherme Lima|Azul|4|21|basico+completo|6
```

(um espaço no nome, o que seria o correto)

os valores vão errados para os memos, por que isso ocorre?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se estivesse utilizando uma versão atual do Delphi poderia utilizar o `Linha.StrictDelimiter`, porém no [delphi7](/questions/tagged/delphi7) não é possível.

Como alternativa, você pode fazer dessa forma:

```
linha.DelimitedText := '"' + StringReplace(Texto[i], linha.Delimiter, '"' + linha.Delimiter + '"', [rfReplaceAll]) + '"';
```

Fizeram essa [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335027/delphi-stringlist-delimiter-is-always-a-space-character-even-if-delimiter-is-se) parecida no SOEn, acredito que a resposta serve para seu caso.

Comment: Linha.StrictDelimiter := True;

resolveu o meu problema.

Comment: Qual a versão do seu delphi?

Answer (score 1):

tive um problema parecido, porem utilizo outra forma e te recomendo utilizar o procedimento split

```
procedure Split(const Delimiter: Char;Input: string; const Strings: TStrings);
begin
Assert(Assigned(Strings)) ;
Strings.Clear;
Strings.Delimiter       := Delimiter; 
strings.StrictDelimiter := True;
Strings.DelimitedText   := Input;
end;
```

deixando o "StrictDelimiter" como true ele ignora os espaços em branco e só separa a variavel com o caracter informado.

chame da seguinte forma:

```
Split([caracter de referencia],[variavel de origem], [stringlist que irá receber os valores]);
```

ou seja irá chamar o split da seguinte forma:

```
Split('|', '0016009993|GuilhermeLima|Azul|4|21|basico+completo|6', Linha);
```

e como dica, como vc esta repassando os valores para diferentes memos, nao salve em variaveis, faça um FOR ou um WHILE que leia a stringlist ate o final e já salve o valor no memo, vai dar uma agilizada no seu trabalho.
E se precisar utilizar este valor posteriormente pegue direto do memo.

espero ter ajudado!